# Как намеренно испортить качество видео с помощью Python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Как намеренно испортить качество видео с помощью Python? Знаю про библиотеку ffmpeg. Как можно сжать видео настолько сильно, что его качество будет приблизительно такое:

[image: шакально качество]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кодирование видео с битрейтом 100 кбит/с:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v 100k -y output.mp4
```

Битрейт можно уменьшить еще больше, но качество видео станет еще хуже

Comment: а как преобразовать эту команду в питон код?

Comment: Через модуль `os`, через функцию `system`, т.е `os.system("ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b:v 100k -y output.mp4
")`